# Can't Connect Spark with Hortonworks Sandbox from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am not able to connect my spark Code which is written on eclipse.

Below is the code please guid me how I can do the same. 
Anything would be helpful

```
> 
>     import java.util.Arrays;
> 
>     import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
>     import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
>     import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
>     import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
> 
>      public class SparkTest {
> 
        public static void main(String[] args) {

>          SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
              .setAppName("JD Word Counter").setMaster("local");

> 
>          JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
>               //hdfs://localhost:8020/user/root/textfile/test.txt         
           JavaRDD<String> inputFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/root/textfile/test.txt");

>          System.out.println("Hello start");
>          System.out.println(inputFile.collect());         
           JavaRDD<String> wordsFromFile = inputFile.flatMap(content ->
            Arrays.asList(content.split(" ")).iterator());

>          System.out.println("hello end");
>       
> 
>          //JavaPairRDD countData = wordsFromFile.mapToPair(t -> new Tuple2(t, 1)).reduceByKey((x, y) -> (int) x + (int) y);
          //wordsFromFile
           .saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/root/fileTest/");

> 
>          System.out.println(" This java program is complete");    

       }
> 
>     }
>
```

Error:

```
> I/O error constructing remote block reader.
> org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout
> while waiting for  channel to be ready for connect. ch :
> java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending 
> remote=/172.18.0.2:50010] at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `localhost` to `ip address` of the hdp sandbox or put `hdfs-site.xml` file in your classpath & make sure all port are open & accessible from outside machine.

Comment: I have tried changing the localhost to IP address but it doesn't work in that case . I tried pinging the HDFS port from the local terminal but doesn't work either. The strange thing is that "wordsFromFile.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/root/fileTest/" this command creates a directory in the HDFS that means localhost is accessible but then I am not able to "JavaRDD<String> inputFile =
sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/root/textfile/test.txt")" read the contents in the textile. how is that possible?